# Ban link comments that don't have any text?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

It happened to me several times on various SE sites that I post a question and someone posts a link as a comment. Sometimes it's a link to another SE question, sometimes to any other resource. And then I go into that link and I don't find anything helpful. This is annoying.

I wish that whenever someone is trying to post a comment that contains only a link, they'll get an error message saying:

> Please explain in a few words how this link is relevant to the question. Examples: "This question has an answer that answers your question", "This link might contain helpful information about your topic", "You've made a mistaken assumption in your question, and this link explains what it is."

Answer (score 9):

> And then I go into that link and I don't find anything helpful. This is annoying.

Link only comments are not useless by definition. And some accompanying text doesn't make that link useful all of a sudden. Often I find very useful posts through links in comments and not all have accompanying text. Often text wouldn't be useful.

If someone asks why his question was down voted, a comment linking a post *What does a downvote mean?* is useful on its own. Why you have to say *This answers your question: ...*?

Answer (score 7):

All this would do is get people to say "check this" or "click this" or "this will help" - you will have no actual gain at all by the addition of useless or obvious text. **Software can't make people think or care.** If you don't want to click the link without more info, @ reply the commenter and ask "what is that link? why should I click it?" and perhaps over time you'll teach them how to comment well.